# How can I store the user given by facebook-sdk and not have one call per request

Tags: python, facebook, google-app-engine

I have the following code (taken from [facebook-sdk appengine example](https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk/blob/master/examples/appengine/example.py#L48)):

```
class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    @property
    def current_user(self):
        if not hasattr(self, "_current_user"):
            self._current_user = None
            cookie = facebook.get_user_from_cookie(
                self.request.cookies, FACEBOOK_APP_ID, FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET)
            if cookie:
                user = User.get_by_key_name(cookie["uid"])
                if not user:
                    graph = facebook.GraphAPI(cookie["access_token"])
                    profile = graph.get_object("me")
                    user = User(key_name=str(profile["id"]), ...)
                    user.put()
                elif user.access_token != cookie["access_token"]:
                    user.access_token = cookie["access_token"]
                    user.put()
                self._current_user = user
        return self._current_user
```

I have the exact problem described in [Issue #23](https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk/issues/23)

**The example from Google App Engine included with the project calls get_user_from_cookie on every request, which now sends a request to Facebook. The example should cache the returned access token so that this does not happen.**

How can I solve this? One concern I have is if I store them on session, how will I know the access token is valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get_user_from_cookie calls facebook in order to get the access token, access token can be cached (using memache) for the duration of its expiration (you also get the expiration when calling facebook for the access token).

The follow of getting the access token should be:

1. Check if its cached on the class (handler) level.
2. Check if its cached in the memache.
3. Restive from facebok, and cache it (for the duartion of the token)
4. Use the access token if failed because of expiration retrieve it (and cache it).

Comment: what happens if it's on memcache and the access token is not valid anymore?

Comment: @fceruti when using an expired access token you will receive an error indicating that the token had expired. you will need to catch and get a new token.